# Elasticsearch Nest - Querying Aliases

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

Does the Elasticsearch NEST API expose access to `/{index}/{_aliases}/*`? I am trying to get a list of indexes mapped to a given alias and I cannot seem to find an appropriate method.

```
{
   "ntdev-events017-v1": {
      "aliases": {
         "ntdev-events017": {}
      }
   }
}
```

http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-aliases.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `GetAlias` method on `ElasticClient`.

Take a look on this example:

```
var indexName = "sampleindex";

var uri = new Uri("http://localhost:9200");
var settings = new ConnectionSettings(uri).SetDefaultIndex(indexName).EnableTrace();
var client = new ElasticClient(settings);

client.CreateIndex(descriptor => descriptor.Index(indexName));

var putAliasResponse = client.PutAlias(descriptor => descriptor
    .Index(indexName).Name("alias1"));
var putAliasResponse2 = client.PutAlias(descriptor => descriptor
    .Index(indexName).Name("alias2"));

var aliasesForIndex = client.GetAlias(descriptor => descriptor
        .Index(indexName))
        .Indices[indexName]
        .Select(x => x.Name).ToList();
var indexesMappedToAlias = client.GetAlias(descriptor => descriptor.Alias("alias2"))
                .Indices.Select(x => x.Key).ToList();
```

Comment: Oh there we go, how'd I miss that... SMH

Comment: This is 'aliases for index' the question was for 'indexes for alias'!